# Regex to validate url AND does not end in semicolon or space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
var regex = /https:\/\/company\.zoom\.us\/j\/.*\?pwd=.*/i;
```

How can I modify this regex to ensure that the url string does not end in a semicolon or space?

```
https://company.zoom.us/j/xxxxx?pwd=zzzzz //Should pass
https://company.zoom.us/j/xxxxx?pwd=zzzzz  //Should fail (ends in a space after the z)
https://company.zoom.us/j/xxxxx?pwd=zzzzz; //Should fail (ends in a semicolon)
https://company.zoom.us/j/xxxxx?pwd=zzzzz;  //Should fail (ends in a space after the semicolon)
```

Comment: `^https:\/\/company\.zoom\.us\/j\/.*\?pwd=\w+$` or `^https:\/\/company\.zoom\.us\/j\/[^?\r\n]*\?pwd=\w+$`

Comment: If pwd is the password, I would not send it using the querystring.

Comment: Replace both `.*` with `\S*`

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird, but isn't the leading carat excluding the string now? Are you able to explain what your modifications are doing?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, it's a Zoom invite link (generated by Zoom), which includes the hashed password. Not much I can do about the formatting of the URL itself unfortunately.

Comment: @Brad The anchors `^` and `$` assert the start and the end of the string. If your string in part of a longer text, you could use the solution of anubhava

Comment: `/^https:\/\/company\.zoom\.us\/j\/\S*\?pwd=[^\s;]*$/` should probably work

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, changing it to `\S*` will work for spaces, but won't work for semicolons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to allow whitespaces anywhere and not end with `;` then get rid of `.*` from regex that allows any character.

You may just use:

```
/^https:\/\/company\.zoom\.us\/j\/\S*\?pwd=[^\s;]*$/
```

**Changes:**

- `\S:`: matches 0 or more of any non-whitespace character
- `[^\s;]*` matches any character that is not a `;` and not a whitespace